# how to adjust left and right background in html css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-bg bg-part" id="left-bg">

    </div>

    <div class="content-hold" id="content-hold">
 </div>
    <div class="right-bg bg-part" id="right-bg">

    </div>

</div>
```

here is the less css code I write.

```
 .wrapper {
        .bg-part {
          width: 30px;
          background: #a2ca46;
          height: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;

        }
        .left-bg {
          float: left;
          left: 0;
        }
        .right-bg {
          float: right;
          right: 0;
        }
    }
```

when content take more place on page the left side and right side's height never incrase. what should I do to make left-bg and right-bg lever to the content-hold's width.

Comment: I have a 30px bg in left and 30 px in Right. It's not show on whole page when more content add to content-hold.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a html table with one row and three columns. Set widths of left and right columns 30px each as you need.